# How to handle in Angularjs ng-show value equals to api data

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-show

I have a scenario that authType can either be "basicUser" OR "adUser" which would getting from login api.

User window would be displayed based on comparison between *api/login*  and *config.js* (Sorry I am confused this logic). I will have a view section based on the authType availability in the confic.js file.

**Example**: *../api/login*

```
{ 
"authorities": [
    {
      "authtype": "basicUser",
      "token": {
        "id": "wTLtMHbIVlKNQoR2htY3LQFlpt4ED3BLKxw",
        "isvalid": true
      },
      "user": {
        "id": "admin",
        "name": "Administrator",
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

**Example**: *myconfig.js*

```
{
"authType":{
    "basicUser":"basicUser",
    "adUser":"adUser",
  }
}
```

**view.html**

```
 <div ng-controller="userCntrl" ng-show="authType === {{authType.basicUser}}"></div>
 <div ng-controller="userCntrl" ng-show="authType === {{authType.adUser}}"></div>
```

based on this I am getting ng-show="authType===basicUser" but expected output should be with quotes(' ').

```
<div ng-controller="userDialogController" ng-show="authType === 'basicUser'"></div>
```

Comment: try this `ng-show="authType === authType.basicUser" ` you dont need {{}} in angular directives

Comment: You can surround the expression inside `''`. See [here](https://jsfiddle.net/Kunalh/04885499/10/)

Comment: @Angular_10 if I use ng-show="authType === authType.basicUser" then I can't expect the ng-show="authType === 'basicUser'" as I mentioned

Comment: @Nishant123 It's a brilliant one. Thanks buddy!

Comment: @SenthilSivaramakrishnan Glad I could help...

Answer (score 0):

Try this code don't use expression in ng-show

```
<div ng-controller="userCntrl" ng-show="authType === authType.basicUser"></div>
```

Comment: this is return the same ng-show="authType === authType.basicUser" instead of expected one.

Comment: if there is only two user, ng-show="authType.basciUser === 'basicUser'" there is default hot coded the user name

Comment: it might be a dynamic value. However I have fixed it. thanks!